# I can't insert lines in my table i don't know why

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add line in the end of the table 'tableau1' when i click on button 'ajouter' after i fill the form  i use the function on_submit() but it is not adding the line in end of the table  so any one had this issue can help me please

here is my function

```js
function submit_form() {

  let cult  = document.getElementById('cult').value;
  let sup   = Number(document.getElementsById('sup').value);
  let pro   = Number(document.getElementsById('pro').value);
  var table = document.getElementById('tableau1');
  var row   = table.insertRow(nblignes);
  nblignes++;
  var td1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var td2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var td2 = row.insertCell(2);
  td1.innerHTML = cult;
  td2.innerHTML = sup;
  td3.innerHTML = pro;
}
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background-color: lightgrey;
  }
```

```html
<table id="tableau1">
  <thead>
    <tr id="head">
      <th scope="col">culture</th>
      <th scope="col">Superficie cultivée(1000 ha)</th>
      <th scope="col">Production totale(1000 tonnes)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bod">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bl%C3%A9#:~:text=%C2%AB%20Bl%C3%A9%20%C2%BB%20est%20un%20terme%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rique,caryopse)%20produit%20par%20ces%20plantes."> blé</a>
      </th>
      <td>
        220417
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        729012
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mais_(homonymie)"> Mais </a>
      </th>
      <td>
        184800
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mais_(homonymie)">   Riz </a>
      </th>
      <td>
        162716
      </td>
      <td>
        741477
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haricot"> Haricot graine</a>
      </th>
      <td colspan="2">
        30612
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canne_%C3%A0_sucre"> Canne à sucre</a>
      </th>
      <td>
        27124
      </td>
      <td>
        1844246
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canne_%C3%A0_sucre">Aracide</a>
      </th>
      <td>
        26541
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        43915
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournesol"> Tournesol</a>
      </th>
      <td>
        25203
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomme_de_terre"> Pomme de terre</a>
      </th>
      <td>
        19098
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const
  myForm = document.forms['my-form'] 
, table  = document.querySelector('#tableau1 tbody')
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()  // disable submit (-> page reload)
  let row = table.insertRow()
  row.insertCell().textContent = myForm.cult.value
  row.insertCell().textContent = myForm.sup.valueAsNumber
  row.insertCell().textContent = myForm.pro.valueAsNumber
  myForm.reset()
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px ;
}
label, button { 
  display : block;
  margin  : .5em 1em;
  }
label span {
  display   : block;
  font-size : .8em;
  }
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding     : .2em .8em;
  border      : 1px solid darkblue;
  white-space : nowrap;
  }
thead, th { 
  background : lightgrey;
  }
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td { background : lightsalmon; }
tbody tr:nth-child(even) td { background : lightgreen; }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <label>
    <span>Culture</span>
    <input type="text" name="cult" required/>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Superficie</span>
    <input type="number" name="sup"  required />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Production</span>
    <input type="number" name="pro"  required/>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Ajouter</button>
</form>

<table id="tableau1">
  <thead>
    <tr id="head">
      <th scope="col">culture</th>
      <th scope="col">Superficie cultivée(1000 ha)</th>
      <th scope="col">Production totale(1000 tonnes)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bod">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bl%C3%A9#:~:text=%C2%AB%20Bl%C3%A9%20%C2%BB%20est%20un%20terme%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rique,caryopse)%20produit%20par%20ces%20plantes."> blé</a> </th>
      <td> 220417 </td>
      <td rowspan="2"> 729012 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mais_(homonymie)"> Mais </a> </th>
      <td> 184800 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mais_(homonymie)"> Riz </a> </th>
      <td> 162716 </td>
      <td> 741477 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haricot"> Haricot graine</a> </th>
      <td colspan="2"> 30612 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canne_%C3%A0_sucre"> Canne à sucre</a> </th>
      <td> 27124 </td> 
      <td> 1844246 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canne_%C3%A0_sucre">Aracide</a> </th>
      <td> 26541 </td>
      <td rowspan="3"> 43915 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournesol"> Tournesol</a> </th>
      <td> 25203 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"> <a href="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomme_de_terre"> Pomme de terre</a> </th>
      <td> 19098 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```